# Store multidimensional array in database: relational or multidimensional?

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I have read numerous posts along the lines of *multidimensional to single dimension*, *multidimensional database*, and so on, but none of the answers helped. I did find a lot of documentation on Google but that only provided background information and didn't answer the question at hand.

I have a lot of strings that are related to one another. They are needed in a PHP script. The structure is hierarchical. Here is an example.

```
A:
  AA:
    AAA
    AAC
  AB
  AE:
    AEA
    AEE:
      AEEB
B:
  BA:
    BAA
  BD:
    BDC:
      BDCB
      BDCE
    BDD:
      BDDA
  BE:
    BED:
      BEDA
C:
  CC:
    CCB:
      CCBC
      CCBE
    CCC:
      CCCA
      CCCE
  CE
```

Each indent supposes a new level in the multidimensional array.

The goal is to retrieve an element with PHP by name and all its descendants. If for instance I query for A, I want to receive an array of string containing `array('A', 'AA', 'AAA', 'AAC', 'AB', 'AE', 'AEA', 'AEE', 'AEEB')`. The 'issue' is that queries can also be made to lower-level elements. If I query AEE, I want to get `array('AEE', 'AEEB')`.

As I understand the concept of relational databases, this means that I cannot use a relational database because there is no common 'key' between elements. The solution that I thought is possible, is assigning PARENT elements to each cell. So, in a table:

```
CELL | PARENT
A      NULL
AA     A
AAA    AA
AAC    AA
AB     A
AE     A
AEA    AE
AEE    AE
AEEB   AEE
```

By doing so, I think you should be able to query the given string, and all items that share this parent, and then recursively go down this path until no more items are found. *However*, this seems rather slow to me because the whole search space would need to be looked through on each level - which is exactly what you don't want in a multidimensional array.

So I am a bit at loss. Note that there are actually around 100,000 strings structured in this way, so speed is important. Luckily the database is static and would not change. How can I store such a data structure in a database without having to deal with long loops and search times? <strike>And which kind of database software and data type is best suited for this?</strike> It has come to my attention that PostgreSQL is already present on our servers so I'd rather stick with that.

As I said I am new to databases but I am very eager to learn. Therefore, I am looking for an extensive answer that goes into detail and provides advantages and disadvantages of a certain approach. Performance is key. An expected answer would contain the best database type and language for this use case, and also script in that language to build such a structure.

Comment: Using an index on the CELL field will speed up a lot your search, also for range queries

Comment: Before discarding your `(cell, parent)` solution as slow, test your queries with suitable indexes. You may need a closure table as well to handle an ancestor search efficiently. Alternatively, if your goal really is to store a prefix tree, I would consider storing only the leaves and querying with the LEFT function, the ancestors can be computed though this makes inserts/updates/deletes more complicated. Provided you're using a DBMS that can do LEFT searches on an index.

Comment: Do you have a preferred RDBMS (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc.) or are you open to using any?

Comment: Thanks, will bear this in mind. Your example shows up to 4 "levels" in the parent/child chain, (e.g. `A => AA => AEE => AEEB`). Is this known to be a fixed limit or could there be further depth to an arbitrary level?

Comment: Abstracting this into As, Bs, and Cs hides the nature of the data, and reduces this to a purely theoretical issue that is unlikely to give a widely useful answer

Comment: @SteveChambers The actual structure definitely has a deeper structure, though it's hard to say how deep. A vague guess would be 20 levels deep max!

Comment: @SteveChambers Just an update (as seen in main post) that I'd like to work with postgreSQL as we already use that on our servers.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Why is that? As and Bs and AAs and BBs are strings, as is my structure. Why would it be a difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The goal is to retrieve an element with PHP by name and all its descendants.

If that is all you need, you can use a LIKE search

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE CELL LIKE 'AEE%';
```

With an index beginning with `CELL` this is a range check, which is fast.

If your data doesn't look like that, you can create a `path` column which looks like a directory path and contains all nodes "on the way/path" from root to the element.

```
| id | CELL | parent_id | path     |
|====|======|===========|==========|
|  1 | A    |      NULL | 1/       |
|  2 | AA   |         1 | 1/2/     |
|  3 | AAA  |         2 | 1/2/3/   |
|  4 | AAC  |         2 | 1/2/4/   |
|  5 | AB   |         1 | 1/5/     |
|  6 | AE   |         1 | 1/6/     | 
|  7 | AEA  |         6 | 1/6/7/   |
|  8 | AEE  |         6 | 1/6/8/   |
|  9 | AEEB |         8 | 1/6/8/9/ |
```

To retrieve all descendants of 'AE' (including itself) your query would be

```
SELECT *
FROM tree t
WHERE path LIKE '1/6/%';
```

or (MySQL specific concatenation)

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tree t
CROSS JOIN tree r -- root
WHERE r.CELL = 'AE'
  AND t.path LIKE CONCAT(r.path, '%');
```

Result:

```
| id | CELL | parent_id |     path |
|====|======|===========|==========|
|  6 | AE   |         1 | 1/6/     |
|  7 | AEA  |         6 | 1/6/7/   |
|  8 | AEE  |         6 | 1/6/8/   |
|  9 | AEEB |         8 | 1/6/8/9/ |
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2b05/1)

### Performance

I have created 100K rows of fake data on [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) with the [sequence plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/) using the following script:

```
drop table if exists tree;
CREATE TABLE tree (
  `id` int primary key,
  `CELL` varchar(50),
  `parent_id` int,
  `path` varchar(255),
  unique index (`CELL`),
  unique index (`path`)
);

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tree_after_insert`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tree_after_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `tree` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    if new.id = 1 then
        set new.path := '1/';
    else    
        set new.path := concat((
            select path from tree where id = new.parent_id
        ), new.id, '/');
    end if;
END//
DELIMITER ;

insert into tree
    select seq as id
        , conv(seq, 10, 36) as CELL
        , case 
            when seq = 1 then null
            else floor(rand(1) * (seq-1)) + 1 
        end as parent_id
        , null as path
    from seq_1_to_100000
;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tree_after_insert`;
-- runtime ~ 4 sec.
```

#### Tests

Count all elements under the root:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tree t
CROSS JOIN tree r -- root
WHERE r.CELL = '1'
  AND t.path LIKE CONCAT(r.path, '%');
-- result: 100000
-- runtime: ~ 30 ms
```

Get subtree elements under a specific node:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tree t
CROSS JOIN tree r -- root
WHERE r.CELL = '3B0'
  AND t.path LIKE CONCAT(r.path, '%');
-- runtime: ~ 30 ms
```

Result:

```
| id    | CELL | parent_id | path                                |
|=======|======|===========|=====================================|
|  4284 | 3B0  |       614 | 1/4/11/14/614/4284/                 |
|  6560 | 528  |      4284 | 1/4/11/14/614/4284/6560/            |
|  8054 | 67Q  |      6560 | 1/4/11/14/614/4284/6560/8054/       |
| 14358 | B2U  |      6560 | 1/4/11/14/614/4284/6560/14358/      |
| 51911 | 141Z |      4284 | 1/4/11/14/614/4284/51911/           |
| 55695 | 16Z3 |      4284 | 1/4/11/14/614/4284/55695/           |
| 80172 | 1PV0 |      8054 | 1/4/11/14/614/4284/6560/8054/80172/ |
| 87101 | 1V7H |     51911 | 1/4/11/14/614/4284/51911/87101/     |
```

#### PostgreSQL

This also works for PostgreSQL. Only the string concatenation syntax has to be changed:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tree t
CROSS JOIN tree r -- root
WHERE r.CELL = 'AE'
  AND t.path LIKE r.path || '%';
```

**Demo:** [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70d28/1) - [rextester](http://rextester.com/WYJ55710)

#### How does the search work

If you look at the test example, you'll see that all paths in the result begin with '1/4/11/14/614/4284/'. That is the path of the subtree root with `CELL='3B0'`. If the `path` column is indexed, the engine will find them all efficiently, because the index is sorted by `path`. It's like you would want to find all the words that begin with 'pol' in a dictionary with 100K words. You wouldn't need to read the entire dictionary.

Comment: This looks very promising. Thank you very much for also presenting the runtimes to give me an idea! (+1) Unfortunately, the requirement has slightly changed in that it has come to my attention that we are already using postgreSQL, so I'd like to continue with that. Would that be possible (without any plugins)? I don't quite understand how the `path` column is used in a search though. How does the search engine use it to find all descendants? E.g. in your last example, if I look for all descendants of 14/ doesn't the software need to parse that path as a string, find 14, look for descendants..?

Comment: I noticed your update for PostgreSQL but I can't seem to open the demo is this an error of SQLFiddle, or did you accidentally provide a wrong URL?

Comment: @BramVanroy sqlfiddle seams to be overloaded, Try this one: http://rextester.com/WYJ55710

Comment: @BramVanroy you should probably read [this](https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns). The author describes and presents solution to this problem pretty well.

Comment: A minor point, I've always included the path delimiter as the first character in the string, e.g. "/1/4/11/". This can make a difference if you ever need to search for any item that references a specific item, such as "everything that touches item /1/".

Comment: @PhilipKelley i also thought about starting the path with `/`, just in order to let it look like a global directory path. Mybe i'm missing something, but i couldn't find a use case. For example: A search `path LIKE '%/4284/%'` would return the same result as my test example, but wouldn't be able to use the index. So i thougt: "Why wasting 100KB?" :-)

Comment: If you know you are working with the root node, you'd still search using `/4284/%`. It's if--and that's IF, it does not apply to all business cases--you are searing for references to that key at any level, that this can reduce confusion. (Think matching nodes 1, 11, and 111).

Comment: @PhilipKelley - sorry i don't get your point. I don't see any use case to search for a single number in the path. As i already wrote in the comment before, with `'%X%'` you'll get the subtree-nodes of `'X'`, but without using an index. And i already have a better solution for that task. So please tell me only one specific use case, which is not covered by my query.

Comment: Hi there Paul. It's been a while but I finally have found the time to bring this into practice! When trying this locally on PhpMyAdmin (MySQLi) I can't seem to execute the query as an error is thrown on `CROSS`, 'not recognised as keyword'. Could you throw me a bone and re-write a query looking for all descendants of a path including itself, for MySQLi? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @BramVanroy It's probably a bug in PhpMyAdmin. Since `CROSS JOIN` is just an alias for `JOIN` in MySQL you can remove the `CROSS` keyword completely. You can also write `SELECT t.* FROM tree t JOIN tree r ON t.path LIKE CONCAT(r.path, '%') WHERE r.CELL = 'AE'`. I don't even remember why i used a `CROSS JOIN` at all :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I made another question because the data has changed slightly. If you're interested, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42519660/1150683

Answer (score 3):

#### Performance

As others have already mentioned, performance shouldn't be an issue as long as you use a suitable indexed primary key and ensure that relations use foreign keys. In general, an RDBMS is highly optimised to efficiently perform joins on indexed columns and referential integrity can also provide the advantage of preventing orphans. 100,000 may sound a lot of rows but this isn't going to stretch an RDBMS as long as the table structure and queries are well designed.

#### Choice of RDBMS

One factor in answering this question lies in choosing a database with the ability to perform a recursive query via a Common Table Expression (CTE), which can be very useful to keep the queries compact or essential if there are queries that do not limit the number of descendants being traversed.

Since you've indicated that you are free to choose the RDBMS but it must run under Linux, I'm going to throw PostgreSQL out there as a suggestion since it has this feature and is freely available. *(This choice is of course very subjective and there are advantages and disadvantages of each but a few other contenders I'd be tempted to rule out are MySQL since [it doesn't currently support CTEs](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16244), MariaDB since [it doesn't currently support *recursive* CTEs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/with/#todo), SQL Server since [it doesn't currently support Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/cloud-platform/sql-server-on-linux). Other possibilities such as Oracle may be dependent on budget / existing resources.)*

#### SQL

Here's an example of the SQL you'd write to perform your first example of finding all the descendants of 'A':

```
WITH RECURSIVE rcte AS (
   SELECT id, letters
   FROM cell 
   WHERE letters = 'A'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, c.letters
   FROM cell c
   INNER JOIN rcte r
   ON c.parent_cell_id = r.id
)
SELECT letters
FROM rcte
ORDER BY letters;
```

**Explanation**

The above SQL sets up a "Common Table Expression", i.e. a `SELECT` to run whenever its alias (in this case `rcte`) is referenced. The recursion happens because this is referenced within itself. The first part of the `UNION` picks the cell at the top of the hierarchy. Its descendants are all found by carrying on joining on children in the second part of the `UNION` until no further records are found.

#### Demo

The above query can be seen in action on the sample data here: http://rextester.com/HVY63888

Comment: Thank you for your quite elaborate answer. Could you briefly explain what is happening in the SQL code?

Comment: Sure - have added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: MariaDB 10.2.2 was released two days after your answer :-) and supports recursive [CTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/with/).

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can do that (if I've read your question correctly).

Depending on your RDBMS you might have to choose a different way.

Your basic structure of having a parent is correct.

SQL Server use recursive common table expression (CTE) to anchor the start and work down

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Edit: For Linux use the same in PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Oracle has a different approach, though I think you might be able to use the CTE as well.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/hierarchical-queries

For 100k rows I don't imagine performance will be an issue, though I'd still index PK & FK because that's the right thing to do.  If you're really concerned about speed then reading it into memory and building a hash table of linked lists might work.

Pros & cons - it pretty much comes down to readability and suitability for your RDBMS.

It's an already solved problem (again, assuming I've not missed anything) so you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have two words for you... **"RANGE KEYS"**

You may find this technique to be incredibly powerful and flexible.  You'll be able to navigate your hierarchies with ease, and support variable depth aggregation without the need for recursion.

In the demonstration below, we'll build the hierarchy via a recursive CTE.  For larger hierarchies 150K+, I'm willing to share a much faster build in needed.

Since your hierarchies are slow moving (like mine), I tend to store them in a normalized structure and rebuild as necessary.

How about some actual code?

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID varchar(25),Pt varchar(25))
Insert into @YourTable values 
('A'   ,NULL),
('AA'  ,'A'),
('AAA' ,'AA'),
('AAC' ,'AA'),
('AB'  ,'A'),
('AE'  ,'A'),
('AEA' ,'AE'),
('AEE' ,'AE'),
('AEEB','AEE')


Declare @Top  varchar(25) = null     --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 'AEE'
Declare @Nest varchar(25) ='|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

IF OBJECT_ID('TestHier') IS NOT NULL 
Begin
    Drop Table TestHier
End

;with cteHB as (
      Select Seq  = cast(1000+Row_Number() over (Order by ID) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,Pt
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Title = ID
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,'TOP') = case when @Top is null then isnull(Pt,'TOP') else ID end
      Union  All
      Select cast(concat(cteHB.Seq,'.',1000+Row_Number() over (Order by cteCD.ID)) as varchar(500))
            ,cteCD.ID
            ,cteCD.Pt
            ,cteHB.Lvl+1
            ,cteCD.ID
      From   @YourTable cteCD 
      Join   cteHB on cteCD.Pt = cteHB.ID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select Seq,ID,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteHB)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select B.R1  
      ,C.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Title = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.Title
 Into dbo.TestHier
 From cteHB A
 Join cteR1 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Join cteR2 C on A.ID=C.ID
 Order By B.R1
```

---

**Show The Entire Hier** I added the Title and Nesting for readability

```
Select * from TestHier Order By R1
```

[image]

Just to state the obvious, the Range Keys are R1 and R2.  You may also notice that R1 maintains the presentation sequence.  Leaf nodes are where R1=R2 and Parents or rollups define the span of ownership.

---

**To Show All Descendants**

```
Declare @GetChildrenOf varchar(25) = 'AE'
Select A.*
  From TestHier A
  Join TestHier B on B.ID=@GetChildrenOf and A.R1 Between B.R1 and B.R2
  Order By R1
```

[image]

---

**To Show Path**

```
Declare @GetParentsOf varchar(25) = 'AEEB'
Select A.*
  From TestHier A
  Join TestHier B on B.ID=@GetParentsOf and B.R1 Between A.R1 and A.R2
  Order By R1
```

[image]

Clearly these are rather simple illustrations.  Over time, I have created a series of helper functions, both Scalar and Table Value Functions.  I should also state that you should NEVER hard code range key in your work because they will change.

**In Summary**

If you have a point (or even a series of points), you'll have its range and therefore you'll immediately know where it resides and what rolls into it.

Answer (score 1):

This approach does not depend on the existence of a path or parent column. It is relational not recursive.

Since the table is static create a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) containing just the leaves to make searching faster:

```
create materialized view leave as
select cell
from (
    select cell,
        lag(cell,1,cell) over (order by cell desc) not like cell || '%' as leave
    from t
) s
where leave;

table leave;
 cell 
------
 CCCE
 CCCA
 CCBE
 CCBC
 BEDA
 BDDA
 BDCE
 BDCB
 BAA
 AEEB
 AEA
 AB
 AAC
 AAA
```

A materialized view is computed once at creation not at each query like a plain view. Create an index to speed it up:

```
create index cell_index on leave(cell);
```

If eventually the source table is altered just refresh the view:

```
refresh materialized view leave;
```

The search function receives text and returns a text array:

```
create or replace function get_descendants(c text)
returns text[] as $$
    select array_agg(distinct l order by l)
    from (
        select left(cell, generate_series(length(c), length(cell))) as l
        from leave
        where cell like c || '%'
    ) s;
$$ language sql immutable strict;
```

Pass the desired match to the function:

```
select get_descendants('A');
          get_descendants          
-----------------------------------
 {A,AA,AAA,AAC,AB,AE,AEA,AEE,AEEB}

select get_descendants('AEE');
 get_descendants 
-----------------
 {AEE,AEEB}
```

Test data:

```
create table t (cell text);
insert into t (cell) values
('A'),
('AA'),
('AAA'),
('AAC'),
('AB'),
('AE'),
('AEA'),
('AEE'),
('AEEB'),
('B'),
('BA'),
('BAA'),
('BD'),
('BDC'),
('BDCB'),
('BDCE'),
('BDD'),
('BDDA'),
('BE'),
('BED'),
('BEDA'),
('C'),
('CC'),
('CCB'),
('CCBC'),
('CCBE'),
('CCC'),
('CCCA'),
('CCCE'),
('CE');
```

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, I would suggest you to use [Nested Sets Approach in PostgreSQL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/24/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-postgresql/). It is XML tags based querying using Relational database.

**Performance**

If you index on *lft* and *rgt* columns, then you don't require recursive queries to get the data. Even though, the data seems huge, the retrieval will be very fast.

**Sample**

```
/*1A:
2  AA:
3    AAA
4    AAC
5  AB
6  AE:
7   AEA
8   AEE:
9     AEEB
10B:
*/

CREATE TABLE tree(id int, CELL varchar(4), lft int, rgt int);
    
INSERT INTO tree
    ("id", CELL, "lft", "rgt")
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 1, 9),
    (2, 'AA', 2, 4),
    (3, 'AAA', 3, 3),
    (4, 'AAC', 4, 4),
    (5, 'AB', 5, 5),
    (6, 'AE', 6, 9),
    (7, 'AEA', 7, 7),
    (8, 'AEE', 8, 8),
    (9, 'AEEB', 9, 9)
;


SELECT  hc.*
FROM    tree hp
JOIN    tree hc
ON      hc.lft BETWEEN hp.lft AND hp.rgt
WHERE   hp.id = 2
```

**Demo**

[Querying using Nested Sets approach](http://rextester.com/KADPF97156)