# Get rows that include value of input in specific cell, filter by other cell, return other cell values

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Thanks to [Paul Spiegel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39687179/1150683) on a previous question, I have a table `tab` in database `dab` and it consists of four columns. A simple, a ID column (`id`) that is also the primary key (int), a `pat` column (varchar(255)), a `path` column (varchar(191)), and finally `has_tree` (bit(1)).

```
id  pat     path    has_tree
1   AA      1       1
2   ABA     1/2     1
3   ABCA    1/3     1
4   ABA     1/5     0
5   AB      2       0
6   BBB     2/1     1
7   CAB     2/2     1
8   ABC     1/4     0
9   ABC     1/5/7   1
10  ABA     3/2     1
```

Given a `pat` value (if it exists), I want

- all unique `pat` values (including the input's if it `has_tree==1`),
- where their path contains the path of the input,
- and where `has_tree == 1`.

So input AA should return `['AA', 'ABA', 'ABCA', 'ABC']`.

Important remarks are that the `path` for the input `pat` is not necessarily a single item 'root path', in other words: it's very well possible that the input `path` is something like `1/12/45/966` in which case I want all the unique `pat` values where the `path` is a descendant of `1/12/45/966` and where `has_tree` is `1`. Another remark is that the path can be very deep, so even if the input `path` is `1`, the result can be many levels deeper, e.g. `1/22/36/88/98/455/878/1205/2555`.

Paul suggested the following query, which worked for the proposed data structure, however as you can see the current structure and requirements are slightly different. (Also note that I have one database with multiple tables. So given a table `tab` in database `dab` I'd like to execute the script.)

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tree t
CROSS JOIN tree r -- root
WHERE r.CELL = '3B0'
  AND t.path LIKE CONCAT(r.path, '%');
```

I am trying to do this with PHP and then calling some SQL database. **Is it possible to write this in a generic, performant form such that it works for PostgreSQL, MySQL and others?** If not, I'd at least like to see the MySQL and PostgreSQL variants.

Building on Paul's example code above, I think it would be something along these lines, but I am not sure. **I am also not sure why the `JOIN` operator is necessary and what it does in this context** (I know what it generally does, but not why it is necessary in this case). I am sure this code can be improved, fixed, and made more general for all SQL flavours? Additionally, I do not see that my attempt below includes the current input `pat` in the output.

```
SELECT t.pat
FROM `tab` t
JOIN `tab` r
WHERE r.pat = 'AA' -- input
  AND t.path LIKE CONCAT(r.path, '/', '%')
  AND t.has_tree = 1;
```

Bonus question: I have indexed all columns except for `has_tree`. Would it be beneficial to index this column as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note: The paths should end with a backslash (`'1/'`, `'1/2/'` instead of `'1'` and `'1/2'`). This is important because otherwise you can not match the the root of the subtree. Example:

```
WHERE path LIKE '1/%'
```

will not match `'1'` but will match `'1/'`.

You can also not just skip the backslash in the query:

```
WHERE path LIKE '1%'
```

will match the root `'1'` but also `'10..'`

Now to your question: If you already know the path of the root node, you don't need a join:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE path LIKE '1/%' AND has_tree
```

To get only "unique" pats you can use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pat
FROM tab
WHERE path LIKE '1/%'
  AND has_tree
```

That's it.

If you don't know the roots path but only the `pat` value, you would either need to run two queries (first get the path then get the descendants) or use a join.

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.pat
FROM tab t
JOIN tab r ON t.path LIKE r.path || '%'
WHERE r.pat = 'AA' -- input
  AND t.has_tree
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/EXZT43019

MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.pat
FROM tab t
JOIN tab r ON t.path LIKE CONCAT(r.path, '%')
WHERE r.pat = 'AA' -- input
  AND t.has_tree
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/DNHRJ83456

Note: As you will see in the domo, you can also use pipes (`||`) in MySQL for concatenation if you change the mode with:

```
SET sql_mode=PIPES_AS_CONCAT;
```

Regarding the index: An index on a boolean column is usually not very usefull. However you can only know for sure if you test it. For the given queries a composite index on `(has_tree, path)` might improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly -- and fast! I'm always surprised how SQL is. A slightly beside the topic question, would the difference between a unique index on path vs a 'regular' on be noticeable with millions of rows?

Comment: @BramVanroy For SELECT statements there shouldn't be any difference. Inserts and updates might be a bit slower with a unique index. But again - You will only know for sure if you test it (or you analyze the implementation). However - I would probably always define logically unique columns as such. Look how many questions like "How do i remove duplicates?" are asked on SO, because people missed to define proper unique keys.